# What is the spelling of the word "whih doe" used in Mexico to refer to people from the United States?

Tags: coloquialismos, ortografía, méxico

Someone once told me they were saying [güero](https://forvo.com/search/guero/es/) which sounds very different from what the Mexicans are saying.

Comment: The normal word is "gringo" which doesn't sound at all like what you've mentioned.  fido, firo, güiro, güido, huiro, huido would be the words that might resemble what you have, but most don't exist as actual words (that I'm aware of, at least).

Comment: It is *the* word I hear when people refer to me. About 25 times more often than gringo, people say "whih doe". I probably hear this word more often than any other word in the dictionary. I could ask someone but they never know the real word. When I read written Spanish from ordinary local people commenting on local news the sentences are barely comparable to written Spanish. I use that as an excuse for myself when I can't understand what people are saying. Maybe it's güido?

Comment: If it's *güido* then I haven't a clue and we'll need to wait for a Mexican to help you. *güiro* can mean *kid* or *country bumpkin* in Guatemala and El Salvador respectively (otherwise it's a squash vine, its fruit, or an instrument made of it). *huiro* (often pronounced like *güiro*) can be a joint of marijuana, a type of alga, or a type of sweet cane. *jiro* can be a type of coloring for a rooster used in cockfighting. *fiero* can be used in many countries to mean ugly or to describe someone with chicken pox, *yiro* can be a prostitute in Arg, but means healthy and in good form in Mexico.

Comment: It might be something related to your ethnicity. Something more specific than "gringo".

For example, the cast of the reality TV show Jersey Shore are sometimes called güidos, because they are Italian-Americans.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guido_(slang)

Comment: http://www.spanishdict.com/answers/143985/how-do-you-spell-the-slang-word-for-white-guy-in-spanish-wedo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm from México and I've never heard the word *güido*, at least in central area and the south, maybe in the border is something different. If you are trying to referring a person from the U.S.A. the correct word said in Mexico is *gringo*, a very common slang to call someone of this country.

In Mexico, the word *güero*, has principally two meanings. The first one, (*in a strict mode*) is a term that denotes a blonde person. For instance, [Kaley Cuoco](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=blonde%20person&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi9hNu8wsLSAhUZS2MKHW3hAVYQ_AUICCgB&biw=1242&bih=580#tbm=isch&q=kaley%20cuoco&*) is *güera*, and [Brad Pitt](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=blonde%20person&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi9hNu8wsLSAhUZS2MKHW3hAVYQ_AUICCgB&biw=1242&bih=580#tbm=isch&q=brad%20pitt&*) is *güero*. The second meaning is an expression to call anyone, for instance:

- *What's up man?* is the same to say in Spanish *¿Qué pasa güero?*

For that, anyone in Mexico can be *güero* o *güera*, no matter of the color of their skin, you are just calling someone.

As you can see, there are not even similar, maybe you missunderstood, or hear someone that wasn't Mexican.

Comment: Also, gûero|a is a pejorative adjective to call or describe a person with quite opposite to white skin color.

Answer (score 2):

Some more answers:

http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Wedo
http://www.spanishdict.com/answers/143985/how-do-you-spell-the-slang-word-for-white-guy-in-spanish-wedo
https://thedialect.wordpress.com/2009/06/26/wedo/
https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/wedo-g%C3%BCero.47551/

> Wedo’ was explained to me by my co-workers as ‘white skin guy’ and now, years later, I have determined that the proper spelling for it is güero with the dictionary definition being ‘blonde’ but used informally as ‘whitey’.

Answer (score 1):

Among my Spanish speaking co-workers (*12 hour shifts - metal plating production - we all work hard) they call me "Wedo" because I'm the only white person on my line that can uphold myself 6 days a week at the same pace as my Hispanic/Latin peers.

It's used as a term of endearment in my situation - but basically can mean a blonde non-white or fair skinned person of Hispanic/Latin decent. Or just white as others have stated. It really depends on the inflection of how one may be referred to when the word is used.

I love it because in my world it means I'm on the side of my peers, not some stale square saltine good ol' boy.

The way it was explained to me was that in this instance it carries the same connotation as "red" or "yellow" bone does in African American culture. If that helps as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Actually wedo is a derogatory term to describe either white people or mix breed white people.  Loosely it's the same as being called a cracker or a honky.

Comment: Personally those derogatory terms never affected me anyways even after learning the meaning

Comment: The proper term for them calling you a white man would be either hombre blanco or gringo

Comment: Otherwise they are being rude

Comment: thanks for your answer and welcome to Spanish Language. Could you expand your answer a bit? As is now it is more of a comment. Go through https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer to get a general view on how to write good answers.

Comment: @Glorfindel I asked you a question the other day in the tertulia chat and you did not answer me. Did you see it? Here's the question again: What is going on with mods here? My flags were not being responded to.

Comment: @Lambie I rarely visit chat these days, and your message did not ping me / leave an inbox notification. I'll have a look at your message / flags this week, that's all I can promise given my limited availability these days.

Comment: @Glorfindel Okay, thanks a lot. But what does SE say about all this? We need at least three mods and we don't have them. Apparently, they know about the lack of mods, right?

Comment: @Lambie yes, they know. A CM contacted me early December, said they couldn't schedule an election until after January because of the holiday season, but I haven't heard anything else. I'll ping them and ask for an update.

Comment: @Glorfindel OK, thanks so much. It's really been an issue. :)